# Having problems crafting SQL statements to get tables and values in JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
String sqlStr = "Select * from inventory where functions" + "like ? order by brand, model";

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
pstmt.setString(1, "%" + search + "%");
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Hi guys, i am having error with this code at `line 2` and `line 4`. I believe that my coding contains errors.

I have a doubt that my SQL query is not correctly formatted. The `pstmt.setString` will set the `search` value to the `?` in the SQL query.

The error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%null%' order by brand, model' at line 1`

Comment: Looks like you're missing a space between the `functions" + "like` , should it be `functions " + "like`

Comment: I think the problem is with search string,it seems to be null.

Comment: @xecaps12 that was the error thank you!

Comment: @DeepakTivari done it myself too many times

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your sql query declaration is wrong. That is why you're getting that error. Why are you including + in between ?

Comment: + operator is used to concatenate two strings :-)

Comment: even so, and despite the missing space, the string just resumes !

Comment: readability maybe (2 lines) best way is to make a string builder and use appends

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);//this is bad use a connection pool    
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("Select * from inventory where functions");   
sb.append(" like ? order by brand, model");
String sqlStr  = sb.toString().intern();//use intern if this function is used many times
```

Comment: You should go to apache website and download the con pool code